# type error with a custom Typescript array to map converter

Tags: arrays, typescript

I would like to implement an arrayToMap function in typescript, so far i did this:

```
export function arrayToMap<K extends keyof V,V>(arr: V[], key: K): Map<V[K],V>;
export function arrayToMap<K extends keyof V,V,U>(arr: V[], key: K, mapfn: (key: K, value: V) => U): Map<V[K],U>;

export function arrayToMap<K extends keyof V,V,U>(arr: V[], key: K, mapfn?: (key: K, value: V) => U): Map<V[K],U> {
  mapfn ??= (k, v) => v; // <--- error
  return arr.reduce((map, v) => map.set(v[key], mapfn(key, v)), new Map<V[K],U>());
}
```

but i get this error at the indicated line:

```
 Type 'V' is not assignable to type 'U'.
  'U' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'V'.
```

How can i properly handle the typings for this use case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your implementation function has incomplete return type. Return types of your both overloads must be assignable to the return type of the implementation function. So it must be written as:

```ts
export function arrayToMap<
    K extends keyof V,V,U
>(arr: V[], key: K, mapfn?: (key: K, value: V) => V | U): Map<V[K],V | U> {
  mapfn ??= (k, v) => v
  return arr.reduce((map, v) => map.set(v[key], mapfn!(key, v)), new Map<V[K],V | U>());
}
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w8v54m)

Notice `V | U` in the return type. Also when you're assigning a value to the possibly undefined `mapfn` it doesn't change it's type. And you have to use [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) `!` to ensure the typescript that it has non-undefined value now.

Comment: You don't need the non-null assertion if you specify a default value for `mapfn`. [Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=6&ssc=2&pln=7&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVwIZRR4CeAKhALJ5gA8A0nKDMCgCYDOcA1sMRAnABqAGkEA+ABQEoALiEBtALrDuvOXQCUcqrUHy6y8QG4AsAChQkWIlQZsuaSXI76jEMzacefASJEBVSWk5PWVVYnUVAFtqBBQ5CW9IuAA3PAAbJGAQjTgAXjE4fy04Fz0DYUDTM3NLaHhkdCwcfEInSmpXJhYOcP4hUUqgwhClFSS4OmjY+LhEtUmVNMzsoVyCoTgAHyL8ua4l9cKUkrL9Q22iwoBvczg4KGAYJCgHQgA6R9YkNGAJCRiYEO+UKgPe7CeEhS8m8YUBcXmxEOGhUKGAAHdSp1yhcdoEJBoNNUAL7mIA)

Comment: yes indeed. too bad TS isn't smart enough to see that assignment right in the middle

Answer (score 0):

It seems that TypeScript can't infer that the type `U` is the same as `V` when `mapfn` isn't specified. What you could do is to split the function into two:

```
export function arrayToMapCustom<K extends keyof V,V,U>(arr: V[], key: K, mapfn: (key: K, value: V) => U): Map<V[K],U> {
  return arr.reduce((map, v) => map.set(v[key], mapfn(key, v)), new Map<V[K],U>());
}

export function arrayToMap<K extends keyof V,V>(arr: V[], key: K): Map<V[K],V> {
  return arrayToMapCustom(arr, key, (k, v) => v)
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVwIZRR4CeAKhALJ5gDCSAzjBALYA8A0nKDMCgCb04Aa2DEICOADUANDICqAPgAUBKAC4pAbQC604aI3s9zaghQalI4ob0A3PABskwDZICUcALwK4ctxqowVklNdl1FOABvAFgAKDg4KGAYJChcVQA6JL4kNGAlJRMwOw9vOCKM%20mSlW00rXXLTFEtRErc9FGAAdzhA4NDw5Tc3AG44gF84uNBIWERUDGx0whJyPs5uXgF9MQkZSWVVVx09K0N-Xup%20sNkfGPjE5NTlojJKajpGFhVCU9a4SwlLw%20WxuCZAA)